# Uso de la directiva ng-bind en tag "option" de html

Tags: angularjs, html5

Tengo un tag select y dentro del select un tag option, requiero usar la directiva ng-bing, pero hasta el momento no me muestra informacion.

Este es mi código:

```
 <select id="SecretQuestion" 
    ng-model="employeeToSave.questionID" 
    ng-options="item.id as item.question for item in questionData">

    <option value=""><p>ng-bind="'_chooseQuestion_' | translate"></p></option>   
 </select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pon el `ng-bind` directamente en la etiqueta option. [Un option no admite otras etiquetas como hijos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/option).